# wild card search in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I wanted to use wild card search in DynamoDB with PHP.
I went through the AWS document but didn't find it. Help me please into this.
I have used filter expression like this:

```
'FilterExpression' => 'userId = :v1 and entryStamp between :v2 and :v3',
```

Comment: Do you mean wildcard search on string attribute?

Comment: yes.. like we don in sql queries ... %searchkeyword%

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html

### ComparisonOperator

> CONTAINS :
>
> Checks for a subsequence, or value in a set.
>   AttributeValueList can contain only one AttributeValue element of type
>   String, Number, or Binary (not a set type). **If the target attribute of
>   the comparison is of type String, then the operator checks for a
>   substring match**. If the target attribute of the comparison is of type
>   Binary, then the operator looks for a subsequence of the target that
>   matches the input. If the target attribute of the comparison is a set
>   ("SS", "NS", or "BS"), then the operator evaluates to true if it finds
>   an exact match with any member of the set. CONTAINS is supported for
>   lists: When evaluating "a CONTAINS b", "a" can be a list; however, "b"
>   cannot be a set, a map, or a list.

```
'FilterExpression' => 'userId CONTAINS :v1'
```